# How to create a recordEditForm with 2 columns?

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

Is there a way to do that? Thanks for your answers

Comment: You can define `column=2` in `<apex:pageblocksection>` tag. Read out  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm

Comment: Please show what you have already tried as it is not difficult to find examples. See [ask] and take the [tour] to understand how to use SFSE.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-lightning-programmatic/steps/handle-data-with-recordeditform there is a trailheead module which will help you.

Comment: @Dev, without seeing your code, this quesion is not only Too Broad, but also seems to lack any sort of research or attempt to resolve on your own, you dont seem to be facing any specific issue that can be addressed on this forum, same with your other 2 questions. Please take a moment to revisit [ask] and take the [tour] to get familiar how to ask a good question, you will get a better r esponse from the community this way. make sure you include your attempted code as well! Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to do so, if you are developing in lightning, the most convenient way will always be leveraging [SLDS Grids](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#site-main-content), however, there are many other ways, you can use other css modules such as [CSS Flexbox Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) or [CSS Grid Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) and even lightning components such as [lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleLayoutSimple) and layoutItem's.

You will just have to distribute your lightning:inputField 's accordingly.

Without seeing your code, the above resources should provide you a headstart to getting something in written.